# error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found or there is no acceptable conversion

Tags: c++, mobile

error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'kingMobile::KingChatFilter *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Here is the playGame.cpp

```
filter = new KingChatFilter;  // here is the error line
```

And in its .h

```
spKingChatFilter filter;
```

ANd the KingChatFilter.h

```
class KingChatFilter : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<KingChatFilter> {
        public:

            KingChatFilter();
            string filter(string msg);

        private:

    };

    typedef boost::shared_ptr<KingChatFilter> spKingChatFilter;
```

Again im starting with c++ and im trying to understand why this isnt working... Thanks for you patience...

Comment: spKingChatFilter filter; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`shared_ptr` constructor](http://www.boost.org/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) that takes a pointer to the managed type is `explicit`

```
template<class Y> explicit shared_ptr(Y * p);
```

This prevents an implicit conversion from `KingChatFilter *` returned by `new` to `shared_ptr<KingChatFilter>` in the assignment below:

```
filter = new KingChatFilter;
```

The preferred solution would be to replace the assignment with

```
filter = boost::make_shared<KingChatFilter>();
```

Another solution that also works is

```
filter = spKingChatFilter(new KingChatFilter);
```

Comment: Worked well with the last option

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to assign a `KingChatFilter*` to a `shared_ptr<KingChatFilter>`. This assignment is not supported. You can do this:

```
filet = std::make_shared<KingChatFilter>();
```

Comment: Where do i put this filet and what does this means?

Comment: I just used the identifier name from your question... Huch, it's "filter", not "filet", but I could swear it was filet originally...

Answer (score 1):

The assignment doesn't work as pointer of type `KingChatFilter*` cannot be implicitly converted to a `shared_ptr<KingChatFilter>`. This is because `shared_ptr<>` makes such conversions `explicit`.

---

You can use one of this alternatives:

1.

```
boost::shared_ptr<KingChatFilter> spKingChatFilter( 
                                          boost::make_shared<KingChatFilter>());
```

2.

```
boost::shared_ptr<KingChatFilter> spKingChatFilter = 
                                          boost::make_shared<KingChatFilter>());
```

3.

```
boost::shared_ptr<KingChatFilter> spKingChatFilter( new KingChatFilter);
```

4.

```
boost::shared_ptr<KingChatFilter> spKingChatFilter;
spKingChatFilter.reset( new KingChatFilter);
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as my experience with Boost goes, the constructor that constructs a `shared_ptr` from a pointer is marked explicit, and there is no assignment operator that takes a pointer. You might write

```
filter.reset(new KingChatFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of types here, but new would return a pointer to a memory location. 'filter' should be a pointer to the class object.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
filter = spKingChatFilter( new KingChatFilter );
```

The problem as at least `std::shared_ptr` and as I think `boost::shared_ptr` has no assignment operator with the right operand of type of the raw pointer.
There are only copy or move assignment operators for the same type as shared_ptr.